# Unable to map a polygon layer and a points layer together due to unknown error

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, tmap

I've tried using tmap and ggplot's mapping functions, and also drew on a few utilities from the sf package. I have a dataset of land parcels that I'd like to visualize as points, and layer them onto a dataset of census tracts that I'd like to visualize as a polygon layer. The point of this exercise is to look at the distribution of points across different kinds of census tracts.

```
la_geom <- read.delim("\\Users\\edwinysun\\Box\\Terner Center_Summer 2019\\Religious Organizations\\Raw data\\LandVision\\06037\\Parcels_06037.txt", sep = ",")
la$PARCEL_APN <- as.character(la$PARCEL_APN)
```

la_geom contains geometries. la is a dataset of all the parcels of land in LA County, with feature columns on use, land area, etc. I'm joining them together.

```
la_geom <- left_join(la, la_geom, by = "PARCEL_APN")

ca_o_map <- read.delim("\\Users\\edwinysun\\Box\\Terner_Center_Literature and_Project_Documents\\TCAC Opportunity Maps Analysis\\2020 TCAC Code for Review\\output\\2020\\final_2020_public.csv", sep = ",")

la_o_map <- ca_o_map %>% filter(county_name == "Los Angeles") 
la_o_map <- la_o_map %>% mutate(o_map = case_when(oppcat == "High Segregation & Poverty" ~ 1,
                                                      oppcat == "Low Resource" ~ 2,
                                                      oppcat == "Moderate Resource" ~ 3,
                                                      oppcat == "High Resource" ~ 4,
                                                      oppcat == "Highest Resource" ~ 5,
                                                      TRUE ~ 0)
                                    )
la_o_map$fips <- str_pad(la_o_map$fips, width = 11, side = "left", pad = 0)
```

ca_o_map contains information about California census tracts, which I filter to take the LA subset, and rank ordinally from 1 to 5 for opportunity level.

```
la_shp <- st_read("\\Users\\edwinysun\\Box\\Terner Center_Summer 2019\\USPS Data\\Raw data\\Shapefiles\\CENSUS_TRACTS_2010.shp")
# LA census tract shapefiles already downloaded in the USPS project. 
la_o_map <- la_o_map %>% rename(GEOID10 = fips)
la_o_map <- left_join(la_o_map, la_shp, by = "GEOID10")
la_o_map <- st_as_sf(la_o_map)

la_geom <- la_geom %>% filter(USE_CODE_STD_LPS == "9101") 
la_geom <- st_as_sf(x = la_geom, coords = c("XCOORD", "YCOORD"))
st_crs(la_geom) <- st_crs(la_o_map)
```

I read in and join a shapefile that contains geometries for LA county census tract polygons, and then set the polygon layer (la_o_map) and the point layer (la_geom) to the same coordinate reference system. Note that there are about 4000 observations in the point layer.

```
tmap_mode("view")
tm_shape(la_o_map) + tm_fill(col = "o_map") + tm_shape(la_geom) + tm_bubbles(size = "ASSR_ACREAGE")
```

Next, I tried using tmap and ggplot to render a map. I keep getting this error "Error in dirname(to) : path too long." After much Googling, I can't figure out what the cause of this error is or what it even means in relation to my code. It's the same error message I get whether I use the above code or ggplot + geom_sf() + geom_points(). I also tried swapping out tm_bubbles and tm_dots but that also runs into this same error.

Does anyone know what how to fix this or at least understand what the error message is saying?

Comment: It sounds like an operating system error with a long path name, but the paths in your script are not excessively long, so I'm puzzled. Maybe something to do with temporary files used by tmap?

It's difficult to help with this because it's impossible to reproduce your error without access to the files you are using. 

Can you provide a self-contained reproducible example that will throw this error (e.g., get rid of absolute paths in your script and make the data files available)?

Also, it helps if you post sessionInfo() output so people will know the details of your R configuration.

Comment: Perhaps putting `C:` in front of `Users`?